# JSONObject parse with gson

Tags: java, android, gson, json

I want to parse my JSONObject with gson. I write some code but doesn't work.

```
public class User {
    @SerializedName("Email")
    public static String Email;
    @SerializedName("Id")
    public static int Id;
    @SerializedName("Picture")
    public static String Picture=null;
    @SerializedName("UserName")
    public static String UserName;
}
```

In my class:

```
User result=new Gson().fromJson(response,User.class);
```

My JSONObject:

```
{
    "Email": "",
    "Id": 1,
    "Picture": null,
    "UserName": "User1"
}
```

Comment: how come we know it? what is not working? share JSON string as well.

Comment: "*I write some code but doesn't work*" that is not problem description. You need to show us how you are using your code: what is your input? why you think your code is not working (error/exception/wrong results)?

Comment: It works after removing `static` modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `static` modifier from all variables and try it again.

**Note:** Make all variable `private` and provide `public` `getter/setter` methods. [learn more...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

Comment: If I remember correctly Gson doesn't need getters/setters. Anyway upvote for pointing out `static`.

Comment: @Pshemo That's why I added it as note just for encapsulation.